# Alloy data binding can't find collection

Tags: backbone.js, data-binding, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm writing a simple app in which i want to try Alloy data binding,

I have a model Region all set, I create a singleton by adding it in the markup

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection id="regions" src="Region" instance="true"/>
    <Window  id="regionWin">

    <TableView id="table" dataCollection="Region">
            <TableViewRow title="{regionName}" />           
    </TableView>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

using the model in the controller just works fine

```
var c = Alloy.createCollection('Region');

var aRegion =  Alloy.createModel('Region', { '_id':'123', 'regionName':'Lazio', 'version': 43});
aRegion.save();
```

but in the XML nor giving the id 'regions' or the collection name 'Region' as value to the TableView attribute 'dataCollection' i got results.

the error is always

Can't find variable: Region at RegionScreen.js (line 34)
or
Can't find variable: regions at RegionScreen.js (line 34)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dataCollection` you should use `$.regions` ($. plus the id you defined in the Collection element).

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection id="regions" src="Region" instance="true"/>
    <Window  id="regionWin">

        <TableView id="table" dataCollection="$.regions">
            <TableViewRow title="{regionName}" />           
    </TableView>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```